# opera inset box-shadow

Tags: opera, css

Opera has had support for box-shadow since v10.5, but it doesn't work on an input element.

```
input[type=text] {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #d2d2d2;
    -o-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #d2d2d2;
}

<input type="text" name="test" />
```

This code works fine on Chrome and Firefox, I'm using Opera 11.01 on OSX 10.6. Can anybody help fix this?

Comment: It seems to be an opera's bug

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like a bug in Opera (I just reported it). You can use `background: transparent;` and it will work (assuming that the background of the container is also white).

Also, there's no `-o-box-shadow`, Opera supported the nonprefixed `box-shadow` property since it implemented it.

Answer (score 4):

It does appear to be a bug, I however had a form where it was working and couldn't figure out why  - stripping it down it appears that adding `border-radius` makes it appear (if you still need the background color and can't use Lea's solution) - if you don't want obvious rounded corners you can use a 1px radius

```
input[type=text] {
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 1px solid #a0a0a0;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px #d2d2d2;
    border-radius: 1px;
}
```

Comment: it's working fine with border-radius in opera great hack clairesuzy

Answer (score 1):

Opera is ignoring many css properties on input elements. Box-shadow is not the only one. Text-shadow or text-transform are also ignored.

Using a button element istead of an input can be a solution when you deal with buttons.

Answer (score 1):

Also, if you need background-color additional to Lea's solution, you can add one more inset shadow, like so

```
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 4px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .7), /*actual shadow*/
inset 0 0 100px 0 #fff; /*just white background*/
```